# Getting language culture not support exception for item level language fallback

Tags: upgrade, multilingual, language-fallback

We had upgraded our site from 8.1 to 8.2 update 4,  we are using item level language fallback but after upgrade it is not working, we have checked all settings,  all are correct.  Because with same settings it works for fresh sitecore instance.  Further investigating found that,  in content editor when we click on language which doesn't have any version,  then item is not fallback to other language. We found that one exception in log file which is as follows,

```
Exception: System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException

Message: Culture is not supported.

Parameter name: name

00000000000000000000000000000000 is an invalid culture identifier.

Source: mscorlib

at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String name)

at Sitecore.Buckets.Search.FacetSearcher.CollectResults(Database database, FacetResults results, Dictionary`2 facetQueries)

at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.Search.GetFacets.RunFacets.Process(GetFacetsArgs args)

at (Object , Object[] )

at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)

at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)

at Sitecore.Abstractions.CorePipelineWrapper.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)

at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.Search.GetFacets.GetFacetsPipeline.Run(GetFacetsArgs args)

at ItemBuckets.Services.Search.PerformSearch(HttpContext context)

at ItemBuckets.Services.Search.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)

at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

So why getting culture not found exception and where to find language culture info in Sitecore?

Comment: Languages are located under System/Languages. Compare what languages and culture codes are contained in that location to what the standard culture codes are. Additionally, make sure you have upgraded language packs, if needed.

Comment: Hi Jamie,  language packs?  Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: is it fine on CM?